# Tabindex inDjango template does not move cursor to correct field

Tags: html, django

I have a Django form and want the user to be able to tab to the username, password and login button in that order.

tabindex does not seem to work in my template. Instead it moves to username, login button and password in that order.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
      <td><div tabindex="1">{{ form.username }}</div></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><div tabindex="3"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
      <td><div tabindex="2">{{ form.password }}</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to define a custom template filter that adds a tabindex attribute to the widget of a bound field:

**How to add filter in templates ?**

**Ans** - You have to create one directory in your app named 'templatetags'. You'll want this directory to be recognized as a `Python package`, so make sure you create an empty `__init__.py` file. Next, go ahead and create the Python file that will hold your tags and name it something like `app_filters.py` or a similar name that is easily identifiable. It is look like...

```
Django Project
  -> my_app
    ---> models.py
    ---> views.py
    ---> templatetags
      -----> __init__.py
      -----> app_filters.py
```

For more [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

**app_filters.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def tabindex(value, index):
    """
    Add a tabindex attribute to the widget for a bound field.
    """
    value.field.widget.attrs['tabindex'] = index
    return value
```

> NOTE : After adding the templatetags module, you will need to restart your server before you can use the tags or filters in templates.

Then, add `|tabindex:n` to the fields in the template. For example:

**your_html_file.html**

```
{% load app_filters %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
      <td><div>{{ form.username|tabindex:1 }}</div></td>
        <td rowspan="2"><div><button tabindex="3" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
      <td><div>{{ form.password|tabindex:2 }}</div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where does the filter go? in views or models?

Comment: OK. but I get Invalid filter: 'tabindex'. I've tried  {% load tabindex %} but that returns 'tabindex' is not a registered tag library.

Comment: Did you register tab index using `@register.filter`?

Comment: Updated my answer please check it

Comment: Yes. I'd sorted out the imports. the error message comes when I try to load the page with the form: TemplateSyntaxError at /login/

Invalid filter: 'tabindex'

Comment: Might be you are missing something, I Updated my answer, it should should should be work haha...

Comment: Thank you for your patience. That now works. I think you should add "After adding the templatetags module, you will need to restart your server before you can use the tags or filters in templates." to your answer to make it complete

Comment: Happy coding :)